# How to label pictorial data when the annotations are given in XML file?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm new to deep learning, and I have downloaded a dataset from kaggle for mask detector. The dataset is having two folders one is annotations and other is the images.
And as I'm going to use CNN for classification, how do I label the data for training and testing set as the data is not labeled and annotations are given in XML file.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dataset?

Comment: @Bhupen Here's the link:- 
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/andrewmvd/face-mask-detection

There are several codes, but I'm not getting a general method for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

See the notebook https://www.kaggle.com/code/daniel601/pytorch-fasterrcnn/notebook ... name tag in the xml describes the label.

Also, I would not recommend this dataset to learn CNN. There are multiple masks in each image, that would add another layer of complexity. Essentially you have to divide each image as per the box specified in the xml. Then label them individually.